# Is there any issue if I use c++11 feature to compile a file while linking it against a library which was compiled without c++11 compiler option?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am seeing some weird crashes on my program. Basically, I have a simplest main program with only one statement "return 0". And the program crashes while clearing a static concurrent_unordered_set (from intel's thread building block library). If I comment out two lines of code, it doesn't crash. I am linking the program against a library built without -std=c++0x flag, but I am compiling it with that flag.

Note that none of the functions are called, other than the constructors of the static objects.

What may be the problem? I am really clueless.

Comment: Post the minimum code which reproduces the problem, and tell us which compiler you're using and which version.

Comment: You say you only have one statement, `return 0`, but that contradicts the rest of your post. Please describe your problem properly including a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it strongly depends on the compiler version and how and what you did exactly.

If you can, just compile everything with the same option.

If not, be sure to read e.g. [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility) and [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-07/msg00031.html) and test thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out why the problem was happening. I was running a test which was part of code used to create the shared library. The main function is "enabled" by defining a macro. I cannot paste the original code, but below code samples will explain the behavior. Please check for "RELEASED TWICE" in the samples. (It has nothing to do with -std=c++0x flag though)

Below is code for a.hpp

```
#ifndef __A_HPP__
#define __A_HPP__
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

void fun();

class A
{
public:
    A() : x(0) { fun(); }
    A(const A& a) { x = a.x;}
    void afun();
private:
    static vector<int> _somevals;// THIS WILL GET RELEASED TWICE
    int x ;
};
#endif
```

Below is code for a.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
vector<int> A::_somevals; // THIS GETS RELEASED TWICE
void A::afun()
{
    _somevals.push_back(1);
}
#ifdef __STANDALONE_TEST__
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.afun();
    fun();
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Below is code for b.cpp

```
void fun()
{
}
```

Now, I created the shared library:

```
$ g++  -c -Wall -Werror -fpic a.cpp -std=c++0x -I .
$ g++  -c -Wall -Werror -fpic b.cpp -std=c++0x
$ g++ -shared -fpic -o libtesta.so a.o b.o
```

Then created a.out for test.

```
$ g++ -D__STANDALONE_TEST__  a.cpp -std=c++0x -ltesta -L.
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
$./a.out
```

Now, running a.out gives errors. The vector _somevals  was getting released twice and hence it was throwing double free errors. I tested with g++ 4.6.1 and 4.8.2 and it was crashing in both cases. But the error output was much more verbose for g++ 4.6.1.

I am wondering why the linker doesn't throw any errors in such cases.